# Data aggregation-loading, time dimension perspective

Tags: sql, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have two questions.

Source table contains data at weekly level. 
We have a fact table with Week_Key, Month_Key, Quarter_Key (& a beautiful time dimension).

1. Would it be possible to load-populate Month_Key & Quarter_Key in the
   fact table for the source data which is at weekly granularity ? 
   Problem here would be the last week of the month which falls under
   the current month & the next month.
2. Anyhow if we load weekly data by populating the Month_Key
   (considering current month for last week) & so Quarter_Key, would it
   be possible to aggreate data Monthly & Weekly seperately at report
   level ?

Your thoughts on this would be very helpful ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple different rollups and you are trying to handle them.

I think the best solution is for the fact table to be at a daily granularity.  This is the unit of time that best rolls up into weeks, months, and quarters.

The time dimension would then contain the week, month, and quarter values for all days.

You would then roll-up the data to the appropriate level for reporting purposes.  If the data is very voluminous, you may also incorporate summary tables at common levels of aggregation to improve performance for users.

Comment: Yes, this is about rolling up. But the problem here is, source data is at weekly granularity. Would it be possible to roll up it monthly ? Every end of month week falls in between two months. So how can deal with this particular situation. One link i found might be userful - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114557/mixed-granularity-weeks-months-time-series-data-in-a-data-warehouse

Comment: @Aditya . . . I would honestly suggest that you switch to a fiscal month definition of month.  Fiscal months (used by many companies) treat months as being exactly 4 or 5 weeks.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff. This is helpful.